# Need to pull Jpg or Png files from a URL in Java

Tags: java, url, download

I have been tasked to write a quickie but reusable program in java to pull about a 1000 Jpg or Png files from a URL. I am not an expert on Java and frankly don't have the time to do the needed research.  I am not asking for someone to write it for me just point me at the best method to do this with Java 7 or 8.  I looked at the past questions and found so many different methods and all several years old so I thought to see if a better way may be available now.

Comment: `Image image = ImageIO.read(new URL("www.example.com/image.png"));`?

Comment: Thanks, that looks perfect.

Comment: Should I post it as an answer?

Comment: @Tomer Yes, cause then OP can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as

```
try 
{
    Image image = ImageIO.read(new URL("www.example.com/image.png"));
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    // handle exception
}
```